# How to get large array from postgres ~70GB of data with minimal RAM usage?

Tags: python, postgresql, ram

I have table in postgres with ~80ml rows (70GB). And i cant execute query like this `SELECT * FROM table`, because if i do that, my RAM have some problems :D

Main approach - get all data and then find similar recods, like search. But i can't get all data to manipulate with, because RAM just overflows like a rocket.

What is the best way to execute all data from postgres with min RAM increase?

Comment: Use limit and offset to get it by chunks?

Comment: Yea, that hepls, but only when i get some chunks of data. But i want all that data in one set. Is this possible?

Comment: You can't get it in memory, but you can store it at disk. If you want to filter them, try doing that with sql

Comment: Well, the RAM usage is not from Postgres, but from the application you use to run the `select` statement. But I doubt you can load 70GB of data into any application. But why don't you apply a WHERE clause to reduce the number of rows, e.g. using a LIKE condition

Comment: I want to get all 'text' from postgres DB and then with python transform that text to vectors, and use that vectors to find similar records or something like this. But if i filter data then i can't get all experience from searching in this big dataset

Comment: Postgres has [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html) capabilities which might let you do some of the work in the database, depending on what exactly it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a psycopg2 ["named cursor"](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html) to fetch the rows from the database in chunks. This will greatly reduce the amount of RAM which *libpq* needs.  But if you process those rows into long-lived python data structures, then that will take as much memory as it takes.